# How to start text from bottom to Top?

Tags: javascript, html, css

How to start the text from bottom to Top?

**I Need:**

[image: see image here]

**I tried:**

```css
.rotated {
  writing-mode: tb-rl;
  transform: rotateZ(-270deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="rotated">
  <span>5000</span><br>
  <span>3000</span><br>
  <span>2000</span><br>
  <span>1000</span>
</div>
```

> Using `<br />` it can be solved easily, but it will be of no used when the screen is small and `<div>` is `position: fixed;`.

Comment: `<br />` still works on mob?

Comment: also.. why is this tagged with javascript?

Comment: last also.. research `<ul>`?

Comment: Have you tried vertical-align:bottom in your css?

Comment: @Anthony you mean just `.rotated {
      vertical-align:bottom
    }`?

Comment: Precisely. You might have to specify the height of the containing div too. Also, a <ul> will work better here because <span> is an inline element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change the order of adding items and use flex like this:

```css
.rotated {
  display: flex;
  height: 300px;
  flex-direction: column-reverse;
}
```

```html
<div class="rotated">
  <span>1000</span>
  <span>2000</span>
  <span>3000</span>
  <span>5000</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Order of numbers is also reversed in this case, unlike in the example

Comment: Just add the items to the beginning not to the end and that's it

Comment: @user9836106: What point? You are asking how to start the text from the bottom. So in my example the first text is `1000` and also in the result the first line form bottom (from start) is `1000`. If the first text in the html should be `5000` and in the result the first line from bottom should be `1000` than you are reversing the order!

Comment: Why height? When the screen height will be long, then the text will not be from bottom

Comment: @user9836106: The height is just for the illustration of that it is not stack to the top of the screen. We can not imagine your outline html, you just need to place the `div` where you want.

Comment: You can change the height to what ever you want, it's up to you, for `100vh` for instance.

Comment: The screen is fixed, some user may use in mobile some may in the computer, how can I imagine the screen also the text will be auto-generated, this is a short example...I need all text to be displayed, irrespective of font size

Comment: What you are asking now is out of the original question I think. Use `100vh` then it will always take the 100% of the viewport height, no matter what is the height of viewport.

Comment: I know this question is out of the above, How can we set the text that if the screen is small then text should adjust them sef...

Comment: And could you define what is the *screen is small*? What you mean by *adjust*?

Answer (score 0):

You can use flexbox (`display: flex`) with `align-items: flex-start` and `justify-content: flex-end`.

```css
.rotated {
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-start;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  flex-direction: column;
  
  /* For demo */
  border: 1px solid black;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div class="rotated">
  <span>5000</span><br>
  <span>3000</span><br>
  <span>2000</span><br>
  <span>1000</span>
</div>
```

Comment: It's going out of the screen while I minimize the screen, the font should be reduced...